# How can I make Google cache delete old webpages and start to index new ones

Tags: search-engine, google-search, google-index

I have a problem concerning Google cache my old content URLs while I created a new website

I have an old website where the old webpages are dead now and created a new website with new webpages.

Because I have old content so when people search on Google for old content the old URLs appear in the search results (as it was cached) instead of the new ones which should be appearing (but not indexed yet), this is because the old content is already indexed by Google and the new ones are not indexed yet.

While when people search of new content the new URLs appear. So for the new content there is no problem, but the problem I have is with the old content.

For that reason above, now I created a new pages with the old URL names to redirect to the new page with the new URL when people search for old content.

My question is what I did to solve this will help the old URLs to disappear from Google cached pages and start to index the OLD content with new URLs instead or should I keep with page not found?

Here's an example of the case I have:

When I search for old content this URL appear in search results --
`www.example.com/Sectionnewsdetail.aspx?id=10132`
which is deleted and land on page not found

So I created a webpage with the old name
`Sectionnewsdetail.aspx` to redirect to the new content page --
`http://www.example.com/Content/SectionNews.aspx?NewsID=13855`

whenever any one click on the old URL on Google my solution redirects him to the new page

So which case will help Google cache forget the old URLs and index the new URLs.
Keeping page not found or the solution I did as explained above?

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. In the future, please ask questions like this there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [submitting your site again](http://www.google.com/addurl/?continue=/addurl). But It could still take a week or two.

Comment: i know this info - i have no problem with my new content - it is indexed as usual no problem

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way could be adding the cross-domain rel="canonical" link element in your old website. [Google Tutorial](https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2009/12/handling-legitimate-cross-domain)

> There are situations where it's not easily possible to set up
> redirects. This could be the case when you need to move your website
> from a server that does not feature server-side redirects. In a
> situation like this, you can use the rel="canonical" link element
> across domains to specify the exact URL of whichever domain is
> preferred for indexing. While the rel="canonical" link element is seen
> as a hint and not an absolute directive, we do try to follow it where
> possible.