# WordPress /page/1-9999 shows homepage content?

Tags: wordpress

my website has pages in google, such as .../page/2/ .../page/3/, and it shows the same content as the homepage which is terrible for SEO purposes.

Does anyone know how to remove those pages somehow? I have never created them but it's just showing the homepage content..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how can i make google cache delete old webpages and start to index new ones](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4203831/how-can-i-make-google-cache-delete-old-webpages-and-start-to-index-new-ones)